# Change inventory in my WordPress by Python script

Tags: python, wordpress, inventory

I created a code to update the stock of 1 product in my WordPress by Python script but appear a Response 403 and I don´t know why. I let here the code to know if someone can help me on it.

```
import requests
import operator
import json
import csv
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
import base64

user = ('XXX')
password = ('XXX')
creds = user + ':' + password
token = base64.b64encode(creds.encode())

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"
}
# header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}

post = {
    'Lagerbestand': 2 
#Inventory
}

url_base = 'https://example.com/product/product_name'
r = requests.post(url_base, headers, json=post)
print(r)
```

The next code is using REST API for Wordpress but anyway doesnt work.

```
import requests

# Set-Up credentials of REST API of WordPress
url = 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/{product_id}'
consumer_key = 'customer_key'
consumer_secret = 'customer_secret'

# ID product to update
product_id = 123

# New details of the product
new_inventory = 50

# Configura los parámetros de autenticación
auth = (consumer_key, consumer_secret)

# PUT call to update the inventaroy
response = requests.put(url.format(product_id=product_id), auth=auth, json={'stock_quantity': new_inventory})

# Checked
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Done')
else:
    print('Mistake:', response.text)
```

Comment: You should add the WordPress code that updates the stock here.

Comment: Hi, Here you can see the code. is it what you refer?

Comment: That's the Python request part. Where's the code on the WordPress side that handles this request?

Comment: I don´t have it, sorry, I dont know what you refer. If I use in wordpress the REST API would be okay?
I read about to make a request post in wordpress by pythong and I didnt hear about to have a code in wordpress side.

Comment: So why do you think that sending that request should not return a 403? Or why do you think that it should somehow magically update stock?

Comment: I was checking some videos and it is how they do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AS6EPzDyjhA

the 403 is forbidden right? so it is maybe because you cannot access to wordpress, but with the user and password, it should be enough right?

Comment: Well you need the correct endpoint to update stock, if you're using WooCommerce that would be https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-a-product and proper authentication.

Comment: So in that case, using what you are telling me, could be possible this? I will modify after your comment in the question (above).

Comment: Yes, you'll get there eventually.

Comment: What do you mean with eventually?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your `user/password` (403 duh). I recommend creating a new user and trying to find the correct credentials.

I have had a similar problem before with my website and creating a new user and using API plugins has helped

Comment: I applied also REST API but it is not working anyway. With REST API is the second code.